# Inserting values using a case statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, case

What I am looking to do is when the figure is 'NULL', I want it to display yesterdays date in the date column.

```
             Date                 Person     Team   Figure
    -------------------------------------------------------
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000        Joe         1     NULL
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000        Tim         1     NULL
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000        Sam         1     NULL
    2017-09-04 00:00:00.000        Ben         1     NULL
    2017-09-04 00:00:00.000        Matt        1     NULL
    2017-09-05 00:00:00.000        Alex        1     NULL
```

Result:

```
             Date                 Person     Team   Figure
    2017-09-13 00:00:00.000        Joe         1     NULL
    2017-09-13 00:00:00.000        Tim         1     NULL
```

I have tried

```
    DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME
    SET @Yesterday = DateAdd(DD, DateDiff(DD, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)

    CASE WHEN D.[Figure] IS NULL THEN
    @Yesterday
    ELSE D.[DATE] END
```

But I get this result

```
    Date                       Person   Team       Figure   Month    (No column name)
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000     Joe      1          NULL    1125    2017-09-13 00:00:00.000
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000     Alex     1          NULL    177     2017-09-13 00:00:00.000
```

How do I change this in the date column in this case statement?

Comment: Your first sentence describes an operation on a column.  You example shows rows filtered out.  I am confused.

Comment: yeah, i didnt include everything. I was just demonstrating - ignore the filtered data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code might be slightly over-complicated for what you're doing.  I would simply say:

```
select  case when DF.[Figure] is null
        then DateAdd(day,-1,getdate())
        else DF.[Date]
        end as [Date],...
```

Comment: isnt this basically what i already have? produces the same result

Comment: You just need to put it straight after the word select and then not select the Date column again.  So the whole code would be:

`select  case when DF.[Daily Figure] is null
        then DateAdd(day,-1,getdate())
        else DF.[Order Date]
        end as [Date], Person, Team,Figure from ...`

Answer (score 0):

So instead of selecting date directely, you have to use `CASE` expression in following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN D.[Figure] IS NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
            ELSE D.[DATE] 
       END AS [Date],
       Person,
       Team,
       Figure, 
       Month
FROM Tbl AS D
```

Answer (score 0):

> What i am looking to do is when the figure is 'NULL' i want it to display yesterdays date in the date field.

If this is what you want, then you would do:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(figure, cast(getdate() - 1 as date)) as figure
```

Based on your example data, I'm not sure this is what you really want, but this is what you are asking for.